# php array_filter without key preservation

Tags: php, arrays

if i filter an array with array_filter to eliminate null values, keys are preserved and this generated "holes" in the array. Eg:

```
The filtered version of
    [0] => 'foo'
    [1] =>  null
    [2] => 'bar'
is 
    [0] => 'foo'
    [2] => 'bar'
```

How can i get, instead

```
[0] => 'foo'
[1] => 'bar'
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After array\_filter(), how can I reset the keys to go in numerical order starting at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401850/after-array-filter-how-can-i-reset-the-keys-to-go-in-numerical-order-starting)

Answer (score 97):

You could use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) after filtering to get the values.

Answer (score 10):

Using this input:

```
$array=['foo',NULL,'bar',0,false,null,'0',''];
```

There are a few ways you *could* do it. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64e9804f126357210708ac6750af93e9e6d7238c)

It's slightly off-topic to bring up `array_filter`'s greedy default behavior, but if you are googling to this page, this is probably important information relevant to your project/task:

```
var_export(array_values(array_filter($array)));  // NOT GOOD!!!!!
```

Bad Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
)
```

---

Now for the ways that will work:

**Method #1**: (`array_values()`, `array_filter()` w/ `!is_null()`)

```
var_export(array_values(array_filter($array,function($v){return !is_null($v);})));  // good
```

**Method #2**: (`foreach()`, auto-indexed array, `!==null`)

```
foreach($array as $v){
    if($v!==null){$result[]=$v;}
}
var_export($result);  // good
```

**Method #3**: (`array_walk()`, auto-index array, `!is_null()`)

```
array_walk($array,function($v)use(&$filtered){if(!is_null($v)){$filtered[]=$v;}});
var_export($filtered);  // good
```

All three methods provide the following "null-free" output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
  2 => 0,
  3 => false,
  4 => '0',
  5 => '',
)
```

---

From PHP7.4, you can even perform a "repack" like this: (the splat operator requires numeric keys)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DmZCH))

```
$array = ['foo', NULL, 'bar', 0, false, null, '0', ''];

$array = [...array_filter($array)];

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
)
```

... but as it turns out, "repacking" with the splat operator [is far less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725812/2943403) than calling `array_values()`.