# Group array rows by column value and create subarrays in each group

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [record_id] => 3
        [task_date] => 2018-10-02
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [record_id] => 5
        [task_date] => 2018-10-02
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [record_id] => 1
        [task_date] => 2018-09-27
    )

)
```

I would like it to be in the following format:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 3
                [task_date] => 2018-10-02
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 5
                [task_date] => 2018-10-02
            )
            )
        [1] => Array
         (
               [0] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 1
                [task_date] => 2018-09-27
            )
         )
    )
```

so that each sub-array contains elements of the same date.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: apologies for the bad formatting

Comment: I was hoping someone would give me some advice on what to try.

Comment: [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way.

```
$inputArray = array("0"=>array('record_id'=>'3','task_date'=>'28-10-02'),'1'=>array('record_id'=>'3','task_date'=>'28-10-02'),'2'=>array('record_id'=>'3','task_date'=>'28-10-03'));

$outputArray    =   array();
foreach($inputArray as $key=>$value){
    $outputArray[$value['task_date']][]=$value;
}

print_r(array_values($outputArray));
```

Comment: Explicit array keys are not required if they are sequential starting from `0` anyways.

Comment: @Xatenev Final output whatever I am printing in last line is starting from 0 only.

Comment: No need to declare `$key` here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Barry's answer, a solution could look like this:

https://3v4l.org/LLaIS

```
<?php

$data = [
        [
        'record_id' => 3,
        'task_date' => '2018-10-02'
    ],
    [
        'record_id' => 5,
        'task_date' => '2018-10-02'
    ],
    [
        'record_id' => 1,
        'task_date' => '2018-09-27'
    ]
];

$out = [];
$datesIterated = [];

foreach ($data as $date) {

    if(in_array($date['task_date'], $datesIterated)) {
        continue;
    }


    $out[] = array_values(array_filter($data, function($item) use ($date) {
        if ($item['task_date'] == $date['task_date']) {
            return $item;
        }
    }));

    $datesIterated[] = $date['task_date'];

}

var_dump($out);
```

We are required to call array_values on the result of array_filter to achieve sequential indexing again, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401850/after-array-filter-how-can-i-reset-the-keys-to-go-in-numerical-order-starting) for more.

Comment: This is no efficient.  I do not recommend this convoluted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$common = [];
$output = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($input as $key=>$value){
        if(in_array($value['task_date'],$common)){
                $k = array_search($value['task_date'],$common);
                $output[$k][$i] = $value;
        }else{
                $output[][] = $value;
        }
        $common[] = $value['task_date'];
        $i++;
}
print_r($output);
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: This will not be efficient.  Please never post code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. All arrays in PHP are associative.
2. Code golf?

.

```
$data = [
  0 => [
    "record_id" => 3,
    "task_date" => "2018-10-02"
  ], 
  1 => [
    "record_id" => 5, 
    "task_date" => "2018-10-02"
  ], 
  2 => [
    "record_id" => 1, 
    "task_date" => "2018-09-27", 
  ]
];

$out = [];

foreach($data as $task)
{
  $out[$task["task_date"]][] = $task;
}

return array_values($out);
```