# Output values of the array only if not empty or null

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, isset, is-empty

I am really new to php and do not know what I should look up to get this solved. I am trying to show only the values if the variable is not empty nor null.

Within an array I assign:

```
$attributes [
    'glutenfree'     => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_GLUTENFREE),
    'lactosefree'    => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_LACTOSEFREE),
    'flavouringfree' => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_FLAVOURINGFREE),
    'corerange'      => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_CORERANGE),
    'engro'          => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_ENGRO),
    'vegan'          => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_VEGAN),
...
];
```

and a lot of other attributes more.
I want the output that it is only printed to the CSV if it is not empty nor null.

Right now I get the result like this:

```
glutenfree=,lactosefree=,flavouringfree=,corerange=,engro=,vegan=No,...
```

The output I need is like everything that is empty/null should be gone but the ones with value should be there. In this example:

```
vegan=No,...
```

For example if I try with "empty" or "isset" it does not work and I get a blank page with no errors.

```
$glutenfree = getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_GLUTENFREE);

$attributes [
    if (!empty($glutenfree)) {
        'glutenfree'     => $glutenfree,
        'lactosefree'    => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_LACTOSEFREE),
        'flavouringfree' => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_FLAVOURINGFREE),
        'corerange'      => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_CORERANGE),
        'engro'          => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_ENGRO),
        'vegan'          => getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_VEGAN),
        ...
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if variable is empty before pushing data to array, like this:

```
#first, create an empty array
$attributes = array();
#get lactose value
$lactose_value = getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, ARTICLE_LACTOSEFREE);
#check if not empty string
if ($lactose_value !='') {
  #pushing to array
  $attributes['lactosefree'] = $lactose_value;
}
```

this routine can be improved using a foreach instruction.

```
$attributes = array()
#all fields now are inside an array
$fields = [ARTICLE_GLUTENFREE=>'glutenfree', ARTICLE_LACTOSEFREE=>'lactosefree',
          ARTICLE_FLAVOURINGFREE=>'flavouringfree', ARTICLE_CORERANGE=>'corerange' ,
          ARTICLE_ENGRO=>'engro', ARTICLE_VEGAN=>'vegan' ];
#iterating
$foreach($fields as $key=>$field) {
  #getting the value
  $arr_value = getPublicClassificationsDescription($classifications, $key);
  #check if not empty string
  if ($arr_value !='') {
    $attributes[$field] = $arr_value;
  }
}
```

Thank you [Dont Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734189/dont-panic)  for your contribution.
Thank you [mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) for your revision.

Comment: I definitely agree that the second bit would be a good improvement, but I think `$fields` need to map the same string keys in the original `$attributes` shown in the question to those constants, like `'glutenfree' => ARTICLE_GLUTENFREE,` etc. We don't really know what values the constants hold.

Comment: Good idea, i will improve this answer.

Comment: thank you. It seems to work, but I still get out some empty values like (glutenfree=, lactosefree=,). Maybe they are not set (means they are NULL?). Is there a solution for that too?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for your contribution. I added those missing semicolons. I did not change the !='' because in this case i wanted to check an empty string, not a empty variable.

Comment: @matt if you `var_dump($arr_value);` you will see the quality/length of the element being processed.  I should ask you directly, is `0` a possible value? Or are they all `Yes`/`No` strings? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (simplest as in minimal modification of your existing code) would be to just do

```
$attributes = array_filter($attributes);
```

before you convert the array to a string.

Comment: ...assuming you don't have any zero values that you wish to retain.  `array_filter()` has greedy tendencies.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43657546/2943403

Comment: I agree @mickmackusa, that's definitely true and I've written some answers before that address it, but in this case I think it looks unlikely.

Comment: I have no way of verifying that all valid values will be `Yes` or `No`.