# php: array_filter inside loop returns array with different index

Tags: php, array-filter

I have this code:

```
$array = [0, 1, 2];
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
   $filtered = array_filter($array, function($elem) use ($i){
      return ($elem == $i);
   });
   var_dump($filtered);
}
```

The result is the following:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 0
array (size=1)
  1 => 1
array (size=1)
  2 => 2
```

My question is why I get different index for the `$filtered` result ?!!
The result should be like this:

```
array (size=1)
   0 => 0
array (size=1)
   0 => 1
array (size=1)
   0 => 2
```

Comment: `... Array keys are preserved`, see the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: What makes you think that the result should be different?

Comment: @NicoHaase because each time I loop i get new array based on the condition, `$filtered = array_filter(...)` `$filtered` always gets a new value right ?!

Comment: @jeroen why should they be preserved ?! when I filter I expect to get a whole new array !

Comment: `why should they be preserved?` Because that is what the function does and how it is documented in the manual?

Comment: Why should keys be changed by removing something from the array? Just as "textual" keys, numeric keys are not changed through filtering

Comment: @NicoHaase I think it makes more sence to get the array with new keys, because when I use array_filter I'm expecting to get a whole new array that's all. But after thinking through I guess it's better to keep keys because in PHP we can have arrays with specific keys (strings for example) and we need them even after filtering, so I guess this is why they preserve keys.

Comment: @jeroen dude I know this is what the function does, there must be a good reason for this don't you think ?

Comment: I think the reason is pretty simple: keys are keys, regardless of whether they are numbers or string values. And relying on the fact that items are "numbered" in any way is wrong from the pretty start, that's not what **keys** are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your `array_filter()` with `array_values()`. Let's try like this way-

```
<?php
$array = [0, 1, 2];
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
   $filtered = array_values(array_filter($array, function($elem) use ($i){
      return ($elem == $i);
   }));
   var_dump($filtered);
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/X1iSF

Comment: ok, this is working but do you have an explanation for this ? because when you have a bigger array I think this solution will cause performance issues, am I right ?

Comment: @SlimenTN Yes Agreed. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43657546/1138192

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time :)

Comment: Surely this is not an answer to the question ("why..."). This is at best a duplicate. Comment from @jeroen is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @jibsteroos yes but I was looking for a solution for it too :)